# I am trying to delete from a multidimensional array using first.last but it returns nil. (ruby)

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

```rb
arr = [ [10, 11], [12, 13] ]
arr.first.last
# => 11

arr.delete(arr.first.last)
# => nil

arr.delete(arr.first)
# => [10, 11]
```

Can someone explain to me this behavior?

If I call `arr.first.last` it returns `11`. If I try to delete `arr.first.last` it returns nil not `11`.

If I call `arr.first` it returns `[10, 11]`. If I try to delete `arr.first` it returns `[10, 11]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `arr.delete(arr.first.last)`

Array `arr` has two elements: `[10, 11]` *and* `[12, 13]`.

You are trying to delete element `11` from it, but it does not contain such an element. Hence nothing gets deleted and `nil` is returned.

You might do delete from the `arr.first` array:

```rb
arr.first.delete arr.first.last
#⇒ 11
arr
#⇒ [ [10], [12, 13] ]
```

The original array `arr` is happily mutated.

Comment: Sorry about being foolish but if I call arr.first.last it finds 11 but if I want to delete it, it won't. 

Probably I will need a step by step tutorial what the program does when I type in ```arr.delete arr.first.last```

Comment: @konkoj `arr.first.last` is a number, but the elements in `arr` are _arrays_.

Comment: @konkoj `arr.first.last` is a member of `arr.first`, not a member of `arr`. Hence, to delete `arr.first.last`, you need to delete it from `arr.first`. Try `arr.first.delete(arr.first.last)`

Comment: @LeoMurillo this is exactly what is written above in the answer.